# PHP Keeps Crashing on Nginx Server, Undefined Variable Error in Logs

Tags: php, nginx

PHP crashes at least once a day on my Nginx web server. Looking in the logs, a crash is always preceded by a bunch of undefined variable errors. However, I have made sure that on the sections of the code referenced by the errors that I always use if (isset()) before accessing the variable that might be undefined ('error', in this case). I'm using fastcgi. Here is an example of the last error I get before PHP crashes:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: error in /home/public_html/[domain]/public/m/includes/index-nosession.php on line 7" while reading response header from upstream, client: [ip address], server: [domain], request: "GET /m/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "[domain]"
```

Comment: those are just warnings. they should NOT be crashing your server.

Comment: Look in your webserver error log. PHP should not crash under any circumstance (eventhough it does sometimes).

Comment: They are just notices, but it's all I can find. The server is configured to dump errors to this log file. I just set the 'debug' flag for Nginx errors, so maybe that will tell me something more.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a memory leak somewhere. I'd check your FastCGI coniguration.